# why i'm not getting the exact image back?

Tags: matlab

[image: this is the image i'm getting after running the program]

[image: and this is the original image which i was reading in imread command]

i'm converting the image values to binary form and then converting them back to decimal and want to display the image, but can't convert them back properly.. can someone help me why is this so?
my image is of size[720x1280x3]. imshow(image) and imshow(d) are not displaying the same images. can someone help me in sorting out this problem? the upper image is the image i'm getting after running the code, and the lower image is the image which i'm reading at the start of the code.

```
    image=imread('my pic.jpg');
    imshow(image);

    [rows cols third]=size(image);

    b=dec2bin(image);
    c=bin2dec(b);
    d=reshape(c,rows,cols,third);
    imshow(d);
```

Comment: can you show us what is displayed?

Comment: @AnderBiguri i've edited my question and have given the images too. the upper picture is the picture i'm getting after running this code, and the lower picture is the original picture which i was reading at the start of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `bin2dec()` returns a `double`, not an `uint8` like `imshow()` expects. The following works:

```
image=imread('my pic.jpg');
imshow(image);

[rows cols third]=size(image);

b=dec2bin(image);
c=uint8(bin2dec(b));
d=reshape(c,rows,cols,third);
imshow(d);
```

Comment: Minor note.  `bin2dec` returns a `double`, not an `int32`.  Either way, good answer!

Comment: Another note (sorry to be a bug): `imshow` doesn't mind taking in a `double`, so long as the values are normalized between `[0,1]`.  The reason why the OP was getting a predominantly saturated output was because the output was originally a `double` type, and most of the values are `> 1`.